# How do I create a CSS drop down menu with boundaries on the left and right?

Tags: css, menu, drop-down-menu

I need to create a horizontal css drop-down menu on which the right-most drop-down list(s) align right rather than left.

Assuming the child UL LI's are longer than the parent LI, they will left-align with the parent LI, while if the right edge of the child UL flows over the right border of the parent UL (menu container) the child UL aligns the right edge of the parent LI.

Use case: fluid page layout w/ 100% screen width— can't have drop menu forcing horizontal scroll.

E.G.

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li>First Item
    <ul>
      <li>First sub item</li> # aligns to the left
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Second Item
    <ul>
      <li>second list sub item</li> # aligns to the left edge of parent
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Third Item
    <ul>
      <li>third list sub item</li> # aligns to the left edge of parent
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Fourth Item
    <ul> # expected to flow over right edge
      <li>fourth list sub item</li> # aligns to the right of parent LI
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Fifth Item
    <ul> # expected to flow over right edge
      <li>fifth list sub item</li> # aligns to the right of parent LI
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS:

```
#menu, #menu li {
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
list-style:none;
}
#menu {
width:100%;
float:left;
position:relative;
padding:0;
margin:2em 0;
z-index:5;
}
#menu li {
position:relative;
float:left;
width:20%; /* 5 list items for main nav */
}
#menu li a {
text-decoration:none;
display:block;
}
#menu li a:hover, #menu li:hover a {
text-decoration:none;
}
#menu ul {
position:absolute;
left:-9999px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
#menu ul li {
border-top:1px solid #fff;
float:none;
width:100% !important;
}
#menu ul a {
white-spacing:nowrap;
font-weight:normal;
}
#menu li:hover ul {
left:0;
}
#menu ul li a {
padding:0.5em 1em;
}
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: http://www.devinrolsen.com/pure-css-horizontal-menu/

Comment: http://qrayg.com/experiment/cssmenus/

Comment: At it's core, I'm using: http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/.  I just need to tweak it so the right-most dropdown UL is aligned with the edge of the menu container, rather than a dreaded overflow (and would prefer NOT to simply wrap the text).

Comment: Is there any reason you are floating the WHOLE MENU? #menu float:left

Comment: @Diodeus it depends on the application/browser.  I've used the aforementioned HTML/CSS in arenas where the whole #menu float is required to clear the following elements in certain browsers (IE).  It's certainly not a requirement for this application.

Comment: See my tutorial (I prefer floats). preview.moveable.com/JM/ilovelists